# Do the bike upgrades affect performance?

Tags: trials-fusion

In *Trials Fusion*, do the upgrades made to a bike (body and/or wheels) affect performance at all, or are all the upgrades just purely cosmetic? There is the ability to buy new wheels and bodies, but it's not clear if those are just for looks or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bike customisation **does not affect performance** in Trials Fusion:

**1)** There is **no indication of improved statistics in the customisation menu**. Normally when you get the opportunity to upgrade something in a video game (whether it's a bike, a car, a gun, or something else entirely), you will be presented with a number or a bar of some sort indicating whether it will make a positive or negative effect. In Trials Fusion, there is no such indication. And I don't think Red Lynx would implement 'hidden' upgrades.

**2)** **In *Trials Evolution*, bike upgrades had no impact on performance**. Each bike had its own performance ratings (visible on the bike selection screen), and installing new parts did not change those ratings in any way.

**3)** If bike upgrades *did* affect performance, **it would result in imbalance**. One of the most important aspects of playing Trials is picking the right bike for the level you're playing, and deciding which statistic will be the most important (eg speed vs acceleration vs manoeuvrability etc). If upgrades *did* affect performance, it would play havoc with the bike selection process (especially since statistics aren't displayed), and would result in players having unfair 'hidden' advantages in leaderboards and multiplayer matches.

**In summary:** I believe that if bike upgrades *did* affect performance, this would have been made evident by the developers, either by displaying performance statisitics, or by mentioning it in a menu or manual.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Yes, the upgrades do affect performance. I own the game and I've done upgrades to the bikes. They do affect performance.</strike>

Okay, looks like I made a slight mistake. Thought they did affect performance, but I guess I was just losing my mind. I am really sorry for the confusion. They don't affect performance.

Comment: Can we please get some facts to follow up on this? You are the only  person to say that the upgrades change performance.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrades are purely cosmetic and do not affect the performance.

Since the game is based on player competition, if the bikes where not the same for everybody, it would be pointless.

Answer (score -1):

The only real difference I've seen so far is between the Fox Bat and the Roach.

You unlock the Fox Bat when you do the FMX levels. The difference between the two bikes is quite stark as if you apply too much gas from stationary, the bike will flip over and you'll land on your face.

Comment: I was referring to upgrades to the bikes themselves (wheels, body,e tc.), rather than the different bikes.

Answer (score -1):

As much as I have understood about the game, the upgrades don't seem to affect performance. They really are purely cosmetic!